# div onclick only in viewable area

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, textarea

here is the scenario:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #000000" onclick="alert(0)">
    <textarea style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:50%; height: 50%; border: 1px solid #FF0000" ondblclick="alert(1)"></textarea>
</div>
```

The main problem is that the textarea's ondblclick event does not get triggered.

What happens is that if i try to doubleclick in the textarea the div onclick is triggered. I want the onclick of the div to happen ONLY if i click in the area of the div that is not covered by the textarea. How can I achieve that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cancel the event. For traditional event attaching, you have to put `return false;` in the end, but I'd advice to use some more modern ways to attach event listeners (namely, `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` for IE8 and older).

Comment: cancel the event ( I assume div's onclick ) based on which criteria ? Cancel it when ? How do i know whether the cursor was within the textarea ?

Comment: On the textarea, set `ondblclick="alert(1); return false;"` instead.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just noticed that you're listening for dblclick events. So, just add this to the textarea: `onclick="if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); else event.cancelBubble=true;"`. The dblclick event on the textarea isn't fired because the click event on the div fires before that, and block the Javascript execution with that `alert`. Then again, consider using `addEventListener`.

Comment: that worked, thanks! wicl read about propagation thoroughly as suggested by Kooilnc

Answer (score 1):

Try reading up on [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) and adding handlers [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Basically you can assign one click or dblclick handler to the `div` element. Within that handler you can determine the originating element and take the necessary action(s). The links should provide you with further information about that.

**edit** [a basic example](http://jsbin.com/omawew/edit#source) (using jquery and one handler function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use timers to detect intent.

Set a timer when click occurs which will get executed if no subsequent clicks occur.

On double-click clear the timer and execute your default double-click functionality.

As below,

```
var dblClickIntentTimer = null;

elem.click(function(){
   dblClickIntentTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      //Wait for 100 ms and then execute 'click' functionality here
   }, 100);
});


elem.dblclick(function(){
   clearTimeout(dblClickIntentTimer);

   //Do double-click functionality here  

});
```